How to get it with javascript / jquery
I am a beginner and try to learn self.
I try to learn the following
Problem 1
Try to change the background color from the input color and the code is as follows
 function changebg(){

      var bgColor = $("#red").val();
      
      document.querySelectorAll(".a").forEach((c1) => {
    c1.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  });
     }
    changebg();
     $("input#red").change(changebg);
});

then i try iike as follows
 function changebg(){

      var bgColor = document.querySelector("#red").val();
      
      document.querySelectorAll(".a").forEach((c1) => {
    c1.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  });
     }
    changebg();
     document.querySelector("input#red").change(changebg);

the above not functioning then i try as follows

function changebg(){

      var bgColor = $("#red").val();
      
     $(".a").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", bgColor);
});
     }
    changebg();
     $("input#red").change(changebg);
});

the above code also not functioning.
<input id="red" type="color" >


<p class="a">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="a">Click me away!</p>
<p class="a">Click me too!</p>

Also need to call  changebg(); in another function as well.
The below code works with 3 input values. But don't know the reason for the above or how to correct it as well.
 function rgb() {
  const bgColor = `rgb(${document.getElementById("red").value},${
    document.getElementById("green").value
  },${document.getElementById("blue").value})`;
    document.querySelectorAll(".odd").forEach((odd) => {
    odd.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    
  });
}

rgb();

Don't know why the code not functioning.
Problem 2
Try to change the the active states of two divisions corresponding elements simultaneously. Also the first button of each groups must toggle classes as well. It functions some what but when the button[0] state is always active once clicked.
But there is no correspondence response from the other division elements.
 document.querySelector('.toggle-container').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.toggle-button')) {
    return;
  }
  const toggleContainer = target.parentElement;
  const btns = toggleContainer.children;
  if (target === btns[0]) {
    
    btns[1,2,3].classList.remove('active');
    btns[0].classList.add('active').toggle('active1 active2');
     
  }  if (target === btns[1]) {
    btns[-1,0,2,3].classList.remove('active active1');
    btns[1].classList.add('active');
  }
   if (target === btns[2]) {
    btns[-1,0,1,3].classList.remove('active');
    btns[2].classList.add('active');
  }
   if (target === btns[3]) {
    btns[-1,0,1,2].classList.remove('active');
    btns[3].classList.add('active');
  }
 
});

});

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.active1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.active2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

<div class="toggle-container">
    <button class="toggle-button">List-0</button>
    <button class="toggle-button">List-1</button>
     <button class="toggle-button">List-2</button>
      <button class="toggle-button">List-3</button>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="toggle-container">
    <button class="toggle-button">List-0</button>
    <button class="toggle-button">List-1</button>
     <button class="toggle-button">List-2</button>
      <button class="toggle-button">List-3</button>
  </div>

All help at all levels for either or both problems welcome.
(if provide with a simple explanation may more useful).

You have mixed jQuery and vanilla JavaScript a lot, which obviously won't function correctly. I suggest going through your tutorial again and studying it carefully to better understand it.

which obviously won't function correctly - that's a far fetched statement

jQuery is just syntactic sugar for JavaScript. There is no reason to think using them interchangeably won't work.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. The architecture of this Q&A forum is such that you should limit yourself to one issue per question, complete with your code and your observations. This way we can help you more directly and efficiently.

btns[1,2,3] is a syntax error.  You can’t reference several items from an array like this.

happy to read all your info's.

var bgColor = $("#red").val(); change to  var bgColor = document.querySelector("#red").val(); and    $("input#red").change(changebg); change to    document.querySelector("input#red").change(changebg);
}); . but not working.

m-sarabi,
Jaromanda X

i write it in fully equivalence with both javascript and jquery now shown in the  post. can you help me now ?


James - can you tell me the way to express it ?

Both $ and .val(); are jQuery functions. There is no .val() in plain JS so you can't use the plain JS querySelector and then expect .val() to work: open your dev tools: you'll see a nice big red error about that function not existing. On that note: use the dev tools, this is what they're for. Also, on a SO posting note: add all the relevant code to your post: without seeing the HTML you're working with, it's impossible to recommend a proper solution.

And finally: one post gets one question. If you have multiple questions, either write multiple posts, or if one relies on the other, post one first, and once you solve that one, the next one might not even be relevant anymore so hold off on posting it until you've solved your first problem.

@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans - definitely follow your suggestions. cheers.

I took the liberty of changing your html and JavaScript code slightly in order to get away with shorter code and fewer repetitions. Here are two snippets that address your presented problems:


const setBgColor=()=>document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a=>a.style.backgroundColor = red.value),
      red = document.querySelector("#red");
red.addEventListener("change",setBgColor);
setBgColor();
<input type="color" id="red" value="#ffdddd"><br>
<a href="https://google.com">Linktext 1</a><br>
<a href="https://google.com">Linktext 2</a><br>
<a href="https://google.com">Linktext 3</a><br>
<a href="https://google.com">Linktext 4</a>



Here is the second update of my solution for your "active/inactive" button problem. Now each button press will change the current button's class in each section through the classes: c1, c2 and "" (=none). The classes of all other buttons will be removed.


const nxtc={"":"c1",c1:"c2",c2:""};
const o=[...document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-container")].map((c,_,cs)=> [...c.querySelectorAll("button")].map((b,i)=>{
 b.addEventListener("click",()=>
   o.forEach(bs=>
     bs.forEach((b,j)=>b.className=i==j?nxtc[b.className]:"")
   ));
   return b;
 }));
.c1 {background-color: yellow;}
.c2 {background-color: red;}
<div class="toggle-container">
  <button>1 List-0</button>
  <button>1 List-1</button>
  <button class="c1">1 List-2</button>
  <button>1 List-3</button>
</div>
<br>
<hr><br>
<div class="toggle-container">
  <button>2 List-0</button>
  <button>2 List-1</button>
  <button class="c1">2 List-2</button>
  <button>2 List-3</button>
</div>
<br>
<hr><br>
extra buttons container, just to show that it can be done 
<div class="toggle-container">
  <button>3 List-0</button>
  <button>3 List-1</button>
  <button class="c1">3 List-2</button>
  <button>3 List-3</button>
</div>



I hope that I understood your question correctly. I changed the class naming scheme in order to facilitate the slightly shorter and easier to maintain code.

happy to get your way of expressions on both problems. according to me it passes 3/4 way. but can you solve it the 1) one as to get a function (); to get it call on other function ? 2) one as to get the both list can change on either upper or lower and reflects on both upper and lower sides ? means if a change / click in upper side on ''List-0'' then automatically active the lowerside ''List-0''. hope you understand it ? if possible help ?

I updated my answer. In the first part I added the "function" and In the second part I shortened the script to now affect all buttons in all .toggle-containers (there can be more than two ...) . Unlike the previous version, it can no longer deal with dynamically added buttons. But that wasn't on the list of requirements anyway.

CHEERS for all your help. If i am not troubling you then can you 1) name the best books with samples and each explanations in detail for javasceipt and jquery. 2) with the (2nd problem = group of button toggle) is it possible to toggle between two classes if we click the specific button clicks each time ? for example first click on  1-List-0 then  add class c1 and if we  (second) click again then remove class c1 and add class c2. Only toggle between c1 and c2 class each time for each clicks. the correspondence change is same for each groups.  (continue -below)

(continue -from above) the same click effects is for  all other buttons that only toggle between class c1 & c2.

I don't know where to direct you with respect to question 1. I can certainly recommend reading the  JavaScript pages on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript . Concerning the second question: I made some changes in my answer. Check it out.

Happy to read /  know the ways you provide with solutions. One
more thing to know that 1) now i stuck with the same with a jquery method. there the toggle works well but when click on the other (name = 1 list-1)  the last (name = 1 list-0)  clicked don't reset the class. the classes not reset on all tags when moving horizontal clicks like = 1 list-0 / 1 list-1 / 1 list-2 / 1 list-3. Can you help me ? continue-below

@ Carsten Massmann - $(".a").addClass("active1");
$(".a").toggleClass("active2 acive1");
$(".b .c").removeClass("");
});
$(".b").click(function(){
clearSelection();
  $(".b").addClass("active1");
$(".b").toggleClass("active2 acive1");
$(".a .c").removeClass("active1 active2");

});
 $(".c").click(function(){

clearSelection();
  $(".c").addClass("active1");
$(".c").toggleClass("active2 acive1");
$(".a .b").removeClass("active1 active2");

});

@ Carsten Massmann - 

@ Carsten Massmann - 
a button
b button
c button
<div class="flr-inner">
   <button class="a">a button</button>
    <button class="b">b button</button>
    <button class="c">c button</button>
</div>
<div class="flr-inner">
   <button class="a">a button</button>
    <button class="b">b button</button>
    <button class="c">c button</button>
</div>


Please put your code into a new question. Do not post code in comments. If you agree with my answer above you can accept it. In any case, we should finish our conversation here and continue under your new question.

Okay. Now created at      https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78968280

How to make the link tag with a class ? for example .bo {
background-color: lightblue;color: black;
}    <a class="bo"........., here the background-color not appear. only the color apply ? why ? OR simply how to add a background-color & color class to each link tag (a) ? because if we don't apply any value to the input (<input type="color" id="red" value="#")  the whole elements in dark ?
